# Display column values from database

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I'm trying to display all the values from a specific column created by my Wordpress plugin (specifically, the ID's). Here is the code I have managed to use to display the column names, but I cannot get it to just display all the ID's. Here is the code:

```
function test() {
    global $wpdb;
    global $table_name;
    $testing = $wpdb->get_col_info('name', 0);
    foreach ($testing as $test) {
      echo $test;
    }
}
```

And here you can see the output:

[www.matthewruddy.com/premiumslider](http://www.matthewruddy.com/premiumslider)

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want data instead of column information. So you need to [another function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class).

```
$testing = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT id FROM mytable")
foreach ($testing as $test) {
    echo $test->id
}
```

---

**EDIT**:

OK, how about this one:

```
$wpdb->show_errors();
echo 'Listing from table: $table_name<br>';
$ids = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT id FROM %s", $table_name));
if ($ids) {
  echo 'printing results:<br>';
  foreach($ids as $id) {
    echo $id;
  }
} else {
  echo 'no results or error<br>';
  echo 'error: ' . $wpdb->print_error();
}
$wpdb->hide_errors();
```

If this doesn't help you either to get your ID's or to figure out what the error is, I am lost.

Comment: Did you replace 'mytable' with the contents of $table_name? And is your column indeed called 'id' in the database or something else.

Comment: I replaced my table with $table_name and above that; global $table_name. This works for all other instances. And yes it is called 'id'.

Comment: I posted a new one, hopefully this works. $wpdb->prepare is not strictly necessary but will help you against SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Here is what I get: Listing from table: $table_name

WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '''' at line 1]
SELECT id FROM ''

Comment: Nevermind. Managed to get it sorted. Didn't have $table_name defined properly. My bad. Sorry. Thanks a million anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Might be a little late for this question, but I think it is still relevant to todays WordPress world and also a situation I ran into creating my own plugin.

So for anyone else, this worked for me. The OP almost had it. However, $wpdb->get_col_info() relies on a cache result for its results so a $wpdb->get_results or get_row or query needed to be called first. :)

I also liked littlegreen's error handling.

```
    function test() {
        global $wpdb, $table_name;
        $wpdb->show_errors();
        $return = 'Listing from table: '.$table_name.'
';
        $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$table_name);    
        $nameCols = $wpdb->get_col_info('name');

        if (is_array($nameCols)) {
            $return .= 'printing results:
';
            foreach($nameCols as $name) {
                $return .= ' '.$name;
            }
        } else {
            $return .= 'no results or error
'.
                'error: ' . $wpdb->print_error();
        }
        $wpdb->hide_errors();
    }
```